# Python code recovery from source code

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, pyinstaller

I have an exe binary that was created using PyInstaller. I have reversed the exe file .
I have some strange files that are called `black_box` and `black_box.exe.manifest`.

When I use strings command on the `black_box` file this is what I see:

[image: strings command]
What is this file? Can it be converted to a python file?

Comment: looks like some packages plus what is possibly a secret ssh key? have you tried just reading it as a `txt` file considering the extension isn't really an `exe` but a snake case one, and if in fact that is an actual secret ssh key I would remove this picture asap

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy this is just an exercise so its ok :) , what do you mean by reading it as a txt file ? I think that some code may be packaged inside. because of the function declarations.

Comment: [like this?](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy actually i have tried it...

Comment: ok so what's the traceback, error? can you show your python code attempts in the post, otherwise I don't know what you have tried so I don't know what or how to recommend a solution, help me help you...

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy what do you mean "but a snake case one" at your first reply?

Comment: snake case == naming_like_this